# Why the down vote on my last 3 question?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, down-votes

I have noticed on my last few questions that they got a down vote and close vote. Are they that bad and how can I make them better? Are they by the same person?

[What is the highest a helicopter can fly?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/63786/what-is-the-highest-a-helicopter-can-fly)

[Which plane has the highest survival rate for crash landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/63795/which-plane-has-the-highest-survival-rate-for-crash-landing) (deleted, 10k rep required to view)

Closely Related: [Question closing is too arbitrary](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/question-closing-is-too-arbitrary)

[Can a helicopter be cargo dopped and land on its own power?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/63782/can-a-helicopter-be-cargo-dopped-and-land-on-its-own-power) (deleted, 10k rep required to view)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've been on StackExchange a long time now and have had a ***lot*** of feedback about your questions and answers on many SE sites, so you really should know by now why they're not very good questions.

For the first question: a downvote can mean "this question doesn't show any research effort" and as the answer says, most of it can be easily found in Wikipedia.  You've also done what you often do: link to some other question without any explanation whatsoever of why.

The second question is deleted, but also sounds like something that could looked up.

I have no idea why you've included that link to another meta.aviation question.  You're asking about downvotes on specific questions, that's asking about closing questions, it doesn't seem the least bit related.

The last question you've linked to is, frankly, an excellent example of a truly terrible question experience.  When first asked, it wasn't very clear, then you edited it a couple times to add links and pictures that weren't relevant and aren't explained, then you edited it some more and changed it into a radically different question.

You've been given this type of feedback repeatedly on multiple SE sites, so you really shouldn't be making the same mistakes over and over again.  Because you had 2 questions get on the HNQ list from here, you're probably unlikely to get a question ban, but if you keep asking bad questions, and never learn from the feedback you're given, downvotes and closures are what your questions deserve.

Comment: I agree, although I am not new to SE but I am lacking in knowledge in most of SE. I have learned so much and still have so much to learn.