# Why was my flag for the "Three endorsements before solo" question declined?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

I am here again for the second time in a week to ask about what types of questions are on-topic here.  My recent flag for [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/74922/three-endorsements-before-solo) question with a current net score of -3 was declined recently.  The poster is asking for information that can easily be found elsewhere.  To me, it looks an awful lot like a homework question.  I’m not I pilot so I could be wrong about the ease of finding a suitable answer but in my opinion, this question is off topic.  It appears that three other people agreed with me.

Comment: You”re not a pilot. There are many users here who are, and have detailed knowledge about the procedure. They may disagree with you, that is why the voting mechanism exists. I’m not a pilot either, and I don’t vote on questions like these.

Comment: @Koyovis Certainly.  I flagged it from the review queue because it looked like a very basic question and had a negative score.  Are you saying that I should completely avoid such questions?

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) has good info. Downvoting is not the same as closing.

Answer (score 3):

The questions lacks a jurisdiction, which was pointed out in comments, and indeed may resemble a homework question.

No knowledge of that topic is required to agree that it *is* low-quality and lacking applicable jurisdiction, but since the answers usually assume FAA jurisdiction when not specified, I don't have strong feelings about it. The downvotes look fair (for the lack of research).

Answer (score 0):

Your vote is exactly that: one of the votes required to close the question. The spirit of this site is that the community decides, and a majority of votes closes the question, a minority does not.

[Here's a post on Aviation Meta](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/question-closing-is-too-arbitrary) on the closing of questions. I personally agree with what is stated in that OP, and I press Skip a lot when I reckon that others are more qualified than I am to make a decision on the quality of the question. Not many people seem to object to a question that can easily be Wikied, since those articles often have much room to be improved upon on this site.

[This one from Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete) is on the closing of posts that are flagged Low Quality.

> You should accept a post (Looks good)
>
> If you see no problems that would warrant editing or deleting and you are at least a bit familiar with the subject. 
>   [ANS] Note that answers that are clear and address the question at least a little, but are fundamentally wrong, should be downvoted, not deleted. A wrong answer still “looks good”.

Comment: Regarding the bit about answers, MSE is general, and makes sense for programming answers. Each site fine-tunes its own policy*, and [here demonstrably wrong answers are deleted](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1476/14897). (Not just here btw.) SE aims to reduce noise and the typical forums clutter. Example: if a core premise is challenged in a comment, and is ignored, and the post can't be salvaged (no major edits allowed). * A famous example is History.SE requiring checking Wikipedia before asking.